# Twitter hashtag search with location

Tags: api, twitter, location

I am using this url to perform the hashtag search:
http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=bluebird&rpp=5&include_entities=true&with_twitter_user_id=true&result_type=mixed

But I also need the location. I could use the id to perform another search specifically on the user but twitter only allows 150 requests per hour so I want it to get done with 1 or 2 requests.

What way would you recommend me to get the location when searching for an hashtag?